# Creating holes in a container at different z-index using any color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been looking for a satisfactory answer to this for a while using both Google/Stackoverflow and ChatGPT, but I really can't figure it out.

I am trying to create a box (main-container) containing 3 x 3 smaller boxes (square). The idea is for main-container to have a higher z-index than square and for square to be transparent, so that when I animate something going through, the animated element (at, say, z-index 1) would be hidden when going through the space between the squares (i.e. the visible portion of main-container), but visible when going through a square.

The code below works, but only using black as background-color for main-container. I would like to be able to obtain the same result with any color.

```js
// Create a colored square element
var square = document.createElement('div');
square.style.width = '2vw';
square.style.height = '2vw';
square.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
square.style.position = 'absolute';

// Set the initial position of the square to center left
square.style.left = '0';
square.style.top = 'calc(50vh - 1vw)';

// Add the square element to the page
document.body.appendChild(square);

// Animate the square
function animateSquare() {
  var currentPosX = parseFloat(square.style.left);
  
  // Update the square's position
  var newPosX = currentPosX + 5; // Move the square to the right by 5 pixels
  
  square.style.left = newPosX + 'px';

  // Check if the square has reached the center right
  if (newPosX + square.offsetWidth >= window.innerWidth / 2) {
    // If the square has reached the center right, stop animating
    return;
  }
  
  // Continue animating
  requestAnimationFrame(animateSquare);
}

// Start the animation
animateSquare();
```

```css
.main-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vw;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 1%;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  border-radius: 10%;
  background-color: black;
  mix-blend-mode: hard-light;
  z-index: 3;
}

.square {
  width: 24%;
  height: 24%;
  margin: 1%;
  border-radius: 20%;
  background-color: rgb(204, 118, 118);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, create a [mcve] - currently the above is not one.

Comment: not really possible to answer you with this code and explanation! Can you put your real code and behaviours you are looking?

Comment: Code given is not rendering what you explain, please add a working snippet or video or image to help u understand what you want to achieve

Comment: Sorry, there was one line that was throwing off the entire thing. This code is copy pasted directly from my VS Code and works, but only with the color black.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a mask for elements. See [this Clipping and Masking in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/) article but you'll have to create the vector yourself.

Create a vector that's exactly the same with the picture you've provided but only the places you want the animation to be visible should be filled. Then simply mask the element that's being animated to the vector.

Here's an example from the article

```css
img {
  width: 120px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.clip-svg {
  clip-path: url(#myClip);
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    red,
    yellow
  );
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/Harry-Potter-1-.jpg" alt="" class="clip-svg">

<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="myClip">
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="40"/>
      <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="40"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34496514)

Comment: @GerritBertier I completely agree. But I don't have the enough experience with masks to provide a solution. I'll try to edit my answer to give more information now

Answer (score 0):

Create an SVG image (easier to use an SVG editor) with `<clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">`  and use it as your element's CSS `clip-path`

Here's an example with 9 squares (you can create squares with rounded borders as in your example. This one is a proof of concept)

```css
body {
  background-color: #4a9;
}

.grid {
  position: relative;
  background: url(https://placekitten.com/408/287) 50% / cover;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  clip-path: url(#clip);
}

.ball {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: gold;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  animation: moveBall 2s ease-in-out alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes moveBall {
  0%   { translate: -20% -20%; }
  100% { translate: 120% 120%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="ball">HI!</div>
</div>

<svg id="clipSvg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1 1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="0.32" height="0.32" fill="black"/>
      <rect x="0.34" y="0" width="0.32" height="0.32" fill="black"/>
      <rect x="0.68" y="0" width="0.32" height="0.32" fill="black"/>
      <rect x="0" y="0.34" width="0.32" height="0.32" fill="black"/>
      <rect x="0.34" y="0.34" width="0.32" height="0.32" fill="black"/>
      <rect x="0.68" y="0.34" width="0.32" height="0.32" fill="black"/>
      <rect x="0" y="0.68" width="0.32" height="0.32" fill="black"/>
      <rect x="0.34" y="0.68" width="0.32" height="0.32" fill="black"/>
      <rect x="0.68" y="0.68" width="0.32" height="0.32" fill="black"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

If you want your ball to be visible even on the outside, than the task is even simpler. Create a black SVG shape with the desired perforations (rounded squares), play with the z-indexes of that shape inside its container, make sure the ball has a lower z-index than the perforated shape.